# use mkl_sparse_?_mm with COO format but return "invalid value"

Tags: sparse-matrix, intel-mkl

I am trying to use MKL for some sprase matrix-matrix tests. The interface is mkl_sparse_?_mm. According to the doc, it should support all formats with the configurations of **SPARSE_INDEX_BASE_ONE** and **SPARSE_LAYOUT_COLUMN_MAJOR** of the sparse matrix.

But, it always returns the error of `"invalid value"` when I set the **descr** with **SPARSE_MATRIX_TYPE_TR
IANGULAR**. Anyone knows why?

My appreciation.

Here are some C codes.

```
sparse_operation_t transA = SPARSE_OPERATION_NON_TRANSPOSE;
sparse_layout_t layout = SPARSE_LAYOUT_COLUMN_MAJOR;
sparse_index_base_t indexing = SPARSE_INDEX_BASE_ONE;
struct matrix_descr descr = SPARSE_MATRIX_TYPE_TRIANGULAR;
sparse_matrix_t coo;
mkl_sparse_s_create_coo(&coo, indexing, m, k, nnz, row_index, col_index, values);
mkl_sparse_s_mm(transA, alpha, coo, descr, layout, x, columns, ldx, beta, y, ldy);
```

Comment: Either coo matrices don't support non general types (likely) or something else is wrong. It's impossible to know without a working example of code.

Comment: What version of mkl did you try? If I am not mistaken similar issue has been already reported and fixed.

Answer (score 0):

You may ensure your `row_index` and `col_index` are actually one-based and in your case **SPARSE_MATRIX_TYPE_TRIANGULAR** needs `m==k`.